# How does --hostname work with `buildah run`?

Tags: hostname, namespace, buildah

Give the example here which has an attempt at setting the hostname to `foo.bar.baz` for the duration of the build,

```
#!/bin/bash
ctr=$(buildah from alpine:3)
buildah run --hostname 'foo.bar.baz' $ctr /bin/sh <<-'EOF'
  echo "/usr/bin/hostname returns [$(hostname)]";
EOF
```

I get the following output,

```
/usr/bin/hostname returns [myHostname]
```

I was expecting `hostname` to return `foo.bar.baz`.

I'm using Debian Testing's buildah package 1.15.2-1.

```
❯ buildah version
Version:         1.15.2
Go Version:      go1.14.7
Image Spec:      1.0.1
Runtime Spec:    1.0.2-dev
CNI Spec:        0.4.0
libcni Version:  
image Version:   5.5.2
Git Commit:      
Built:           Wed Dec 31 18:00:00 1969
OS/Arch:         linux/amd64
```

But I've also tested it on 1.17,

```
❯ buildah version
Version:         1.17.0
Go Version:      go1.15.2
Image Spec:      1.0.1-dev
Runtime Spec:    1.0.2-dev
CNI Spec:        0.4.0
libcni Version:  
image Version:   5.7.0
Git Commit:      
Built:           Wed Dec 31 18:00:00 1969
OS/Arch:         linux/amd64
```

Comment: what is the version of your installed buildah and if it's rootless or not?

Comment: Yes, it's rootless. I'm on Debian testing, buildah version 1.15.2 (image-spec 1.0.1, runtime-spec 1.0.2-dev)

Comment: at rootless you cannot change the hostname

Comment: @αғsнιη is that documented anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I filed this as a [bug on GitHub (#2775)](https://github.com/containers/buildah/issues/2775).

It seems it's hardwired but not documented, from irc.freenode.net/#podman

> nalind> `buildah run` is hardwired to disable UTS namespace in rootless mode, don't remember why
>
> ...
>
> nalind> EvanCarroll: unless it's a limitation we put in place for the sake of runc or crun, not being able to use a private UTS namespace in `buildah run` a fixable bug